# Camera permissions are not requested but are still working

Tags: android, android-permissions

Manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:requiredFeature="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:requiredFeature="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:requiredFeature="true"/>
```

The app does not request the camera permissions but it is still working. 
I am able to use the camera using the following intent:

```kotlin
val takePhotoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

I am not sure why.

This is despite the fact that no permissions are granted to the app: 
[image]

Comment: The permission might be already granted... so, uninstall your app, and then reinstall it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this works is that your app is not getting access to any of:

- The camera itself
- The user's internal/external storage
- The user's existing photos

All you're getting is the opportunity to ask the user to take a photo and return that photo to you.  Because the user needs to affirmatively consent as part of the process, no permission is required.

This model also has the benefit of allowing apps to capture photos even if the user would not entrust them with camera or storage permissions.  They can rest assured that the app only got access to the single photo that the user took.  The same principle applies when asking the user to select a photo as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because you're not actually getting control of the camera yourself. You're asking to launch the camera app. There's no way in this for your app to take a photo without user intervention, so it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because you are running it on an older api or have already gave these privileges to the app for once. The other possibility: your device is rooted.